# Analog of 'ave' in plyr?

Tags: r, grouping, plyr

R's `ave()` function is way more useful than its name suggests - it's basically a version of `tapply()` that lets you return a vector the same length as the input, and slots those values back into the same order as the input for you.

```
> x <- 1:10
> ave(x, x %% 2, FUN=function(d) d-mean(d))
 [1] -4 -4 -2 -2  0  0  2  2  4  4
```

You can achieve a similar effect with `ddply()`, but it requires a couple extra copies of the data, as well as a couple auxiliary variables:

```
> x <- 1:10
> val <- ddply(data.frame(x=x, id=1:10), .(x %% 2), 
     function(d) {d$y <- d$x-mean(d$x); d})
> val[order(val$id),]$y
 [1] -4 -4 -2 -2  0  0  2  2  4  4
```

Is there some other `plyr` technique that matches the lightweight approach I can get with `ave()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can shorten the `ddply` code somewhat by using `transform`:

```
ddply(data.frame(x=x, id=1:10), .(x %% 2),transform,y = x - mean(x))
```

but I don't think that `ddply` and other **plyr** functions are really meant to replicate the functionality of `ave` that you describe. For splitting and recombining single atomic vectors, `tapply` (and `ave`) are probably the right tools for the job.

Comment: Yes, the plyr equivalent of `ave` is `ave` ;)  Plyr is fundamentally based around working with objects bigger than just single vectors - base R provides everything you need there.

Answer (score 5):

I recently wrote [a blog post](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/) comparing ave, ddply, and data.table in terms of speed. I would recommend you take a look at data.table, it might prove beneficial. Sorry in advance if anyone takes offence to the self promotion.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the other kid on the block. =)  Thanks for the self-promotion, I'll definitely look into that.